# Can someone help me understand this error:

Tags: python, twisted

I never know how to read these. It would be helpful if someone could help me understand this one, and maybe give advice on how to read these in general?

```
D:\>python captain2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "captain2.py", line 2, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import reactor
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\reactor.py", line 37, in
<module>
    from twisted.internet import default
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\default.py", line 50, in
<module>
    install = _getInstallFunction(platform)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\default.py", line 46, in
_getInstallFunction
    from twisted.internet.selectreactor import install
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\selectreactor.py", line 1
4, in <module>
    from zope.interface import implements
ImportError: No module named zope.interface
```

Comment: if you have pip or easy_install try running `sudo pip install zope` or `sudo easy_install zope` and confirm you have that package.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a stack traceback, Python lists the current call stack, in the order the calls happened. So, first your code in `captain2.py`:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
```

Then the `reactor` module did:

```
from twisted.internet import default
```

and so on, until `selectreactor.py` did:

```
from zope.interface import implements
```

and apparently there does not exist a `zope.interface` module on your system.